# Compare Facebook array of friendslist to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, facebook-graph-api

I retrieve an array of friends using the graph api, and have a list of users on a MySQL table.  I (sort of) know how to use join, but I don't know how you would go about comparing an array in php to a mysql table.  Basically the Facebook ID is what I am looking to match, and then drawing all of the data from the row if it matches.

Thanks,
Michael Amici

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fb_id IN (12345,1234,123,12346)");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo $row['username'];
}
```

Note: Make sure you add an index on the column that holds the facebook ids.

Comment: ok looks good but the thing is if i have 600 friends on Facebook and my database table only has 13 of those friends and i plug in all 600 into the query, what happens with all those null selections?

Comment: Nothing :) It won't show up as a result. If you have 6 out of the 600 users, there will be 6 resulting rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array_with_ids = array('123', '124', '125');
$sql_ids = implode(',', $array_with_ids);

// Select friends already added to db
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fb_users WHERE fb_id IN (".$sql_ids.")");

// Find friends, that are in your db, but not in the array
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fb_users WHERE fb_id NOT IN (".$sql_ids.")");

foreach($array_with_ids AS $fb_id)
{
    // Add new friends
    mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO fb_users VALUES (".$fb_id.", ".$name.", ".$stuff.")";
}
```

Be sure to use a primary index for fb_id

Comment: No, just the quick and dirty method. :-)