# How to join results from Facebook api query with my own MySQL table

Tags: android, mysql, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

What is the best way to join the results of a Facebook api query with my own MySQL database?
I am trying to display a list of blogs that my friends are following.
I am using the android Facebook sdk 3.0. Here is how I am getting a list of my friends, which works fine.

```
Session session  = Session.getActiveSession();

    if(session.isOpened())
    {
        Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) 
            {
                updateUI(users);
            }


        });
    }
```

I need to join these results with my own database in order to display a list of blogs that my friends are following. I have a database table like this:

```
Table name: blog_followers
Columns: id, user_id, blog_id
```

The result should be this: 7 of your friends are following "How to grill food".

I have a users table also:

```
Table name: users
Columns: id, email, facebook_id
```

I just need to do a join using my friends' facebook id's, my users table, and my blog_followers table. 
What is the best way to do this for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Filter your table using the SQL [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator, as shown in [Compare Facebook array of friendslist to MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10923425); or
2. Push the Facebook resultset into a temporary table, then join that to the existing data within the RDBMS as normal.

   As documented under [`CREATE TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html):

   > #### Temporary Tables
   >
   > You can use the `TEMPORARY` keyword when creating a table. A `TEMPORARY` table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed. This means that two different connections can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-`TEMPORARY` table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table is dropped.) To create temporary tables, you must have the [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-temporary-tables) privilege.